# Parsing JSON response from web api in Android

Tags: android, json

i get a response from web api in the following format

```
{
    "userId": "7c29a313-40ab-4927-bc43-7fc8518fe247",
    "userName": "k@ons.com",
    "email": "k@ons.com",
    "mobileNumber": null,
    "redirectTo": "none"
}
```

I try to parse it with following code

```
tvUserName.setText(new JSONObject(response).get("userName").toString());
```

but i get the following error

```
Value {"userId":"7c29a313-40ab-4927-bc43-7fc8518fe247","userName":"k@ons.com","email":"k@ons.com","mobileNumber":null,"redirectTo":"none"} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

i can't find any mistake in the json file format, but still why do i get this error?

the async task is as follows

```
class authenticateLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private Exception exception;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //responseView.setText("");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {

        String result = "Error has occured";

        try {
            URL url;
            URLConnection urlConn;

            url = new URL(API_URL);
            urlConn = url.openConnection();
            urlConn.setDoInput(true);
            urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Host", "api_app.azurewebsites.net");
            urlConn.connect();

            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
            jsonParam.put("loginid", "login");
            jsonParam.put("password", "pass");

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(urlConn.getOutputStream());
            out.print(jsonParam);
            out.close();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
                bufferedReader.close();
                result = stringBuilder.toString();

        }
        catch (java.io.IOException ex)
        {
            result = "IO-Error: "  + ex.getMessage();
            Log.e("IO Error Tag",ex.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
        catch (org.json.JSONException ex)
        {
            result = "JSON-Error: "  + ex.getMessage();
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if(response == null) {
            response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.i("INFO", response);
        //responseView.setText(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: missing parenthesis on your object creation `(new JSONObject(response)).get(....`

Comment: nope, it didn't help

Comment: Can you show ur Asnyc task??

Comment: edit the question to add Async task

Comment: You know about JsonParser class??@LakshmanPilaka

Comment: sounds like your server is responding with some extra non printable junk characters. You might need to try stripping those out.

Comment: maybe you should see if you are getting extra characters prefixed to the string, which is causing the JSON parse exception

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a case of extra characters getting prefixed / suffixed. I could figure it out by copying the response string in `(new JSONObject(response))` and i could get the expected results. Can you please help how should i identify the unwanted characters? `.trim()` didn't help

Comment: with lot of search i could achieve what i want, but please help in getting a better solution please. this is just too much overhead i guess.

Comment: `           tvUserName.setText(new JSONObject(response.substring(response.indexOf("{")).replace("\\","")).getString("userName"));
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use instead:

```
tvUserName.setText(new JSONObject(response).getString("userName"));
```

Comment: the problem is not with "getting" the `userName`. It's about converting the string to `JSONObject`. Its unable to even parse

Comment: @Xoce i have changed the data and entered a mobile number to avoid the null. No luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Create JsonParser.java And just copy-paste this code

**JsonParser.java**

```
package info.tranetech.laundry.adapter;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONParser {
    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;

    public JSONParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
        return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
    }

    /**
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * @params - http request params
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }
}
```

And call in doInBackground like this

```
  @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            JSONParser JP = new JSONParser();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = JP.makeServiceCall("http://.com/mis/Laundry/men_dry.php", JSONParser.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {


                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                   String A = jsonObj.getString("userId").toString();   

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: your JsonParser doesn't parse a json. it's just executing the API call. In the background you are doing the parsing. If you look at my code, its exactly what i do `jsonObj.getString` where i get the error. and also, httpClient is no longer supported in > SDK 23